# How to Change Title of field in popup kendo grid as same as kendo grid by html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, popup

I use kendo ui grid in project,I have a problem in popup kendo grid.
I have a kendo grid. and i customize title of column in grid by html helper.but in edit popup window title not set as same as kendo grid.

```
    <div class="k-rtl">

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoSample.Models.Person>()
   .Name("grid")
   .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.PersonId).Title("کد").Width(100).Sortable(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("نام").Width(200).Sortable(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Family).Title("نام خانوادگی").Sortable(false);
        columns.Command(c => { c.Edit().Text("ویرایش").CancelText("انصراف").UpdateText("ذخیره"); c.Destroy().Text("حذف"); });            
    })
.Pageable()

.ToolBar(s => { s.Create().Text("ایجاد"); })
.Editable(c => { c.TemplateName("Default").Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp); c.Window(x => x.Title("ویرایش")); })


.Scrollable()
.Sortable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
                            .Model(c => c.Id(p => p.PersonId))
                            .Create(c => c.Action("Read", "Home"))

    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "Grid"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Grid"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Grid"))                                


                            .ServerOperation(true)
    .PageSize(8)
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_read", "Home"))
 )
 .Sortable()
 .Filterable()
 )

</div>
```

please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this issue by use EditorTemplates in view.